# Connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file ///android_asset/www/index.html)

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have an error when I run my app on `ionic cordova run android`. 
My error is : **Connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file ///android_asset/www/index.html)**
I try to resolve it with forums that exists with this solution :

**1)Rename your index.html to “main.html”**

**2)Create a new “index.html” and put the following content into it:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>title</title>
   <script>
     window.location='./main.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Or modify in the config.xml this line :**

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

**to this line :**

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="70000" />
```

But when I run my app after saving my new code, the error still appear and when I return into my code, I see that the code is **still the same** and not has been modified (even if I modified it like I sayed previously !)

Someone know how to resolve my problem ?

Thanks in advance, 
Caroline

Comment: In which version of Android that appears? Is it an older version?

Comment: Yes my smartphone is an Android 4.1.2 API 16

Answer (score 1):

I had that error with one application and I solved it with [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html).

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

After installation you may have to adjust the design but the error will no longer appear.

- [More about Crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview).

---

Optional *config.xml* settings:

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Cordova android platform:

```
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android
```

Comment: I try but it does the same thing... when I run the app my files aren't modified... it stays with the code that is added by default despite my backup.

Answer (score 0):

Add and Remove android platform
`ionic platform rm android`
`ionic platform add android`

Comment: I try but it does the same thing... when I run the app my files aren't modified... it stays with the code that is added by default despite my backup.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer but it allowed me to see my app without the error message.

When I run my app with the terminal `ionic cordova run android` the error still persist.

But if I run my app with Android Studio it's works !